# Invalid Tag static expected endblock

Tags: django

I am new django. I'm practicing it after finishing youtube videos. I'm facing the following error

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 42: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

The problem that it tells me that it can't find the endblock tag but I've put it at the end of the code. I don't know what causes this problem or how to solve it I need help please
my html

```
{% extends "Books/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  
    <div class="page" id="page">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="main-content">
          {% for book in books %}
            <div class="container">
              <div class="img">
                <img
                  src="{{ book.image.url }}"
                  width="250px"
                  height="300px"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                <a href="{% url 'details' book.id %}" target="_blank"> {{ book.title }} </a>
              </div>
              <p class="description">{{ book.mini_description }}</p>
              <p class="category">
                {% for categ in book.category.all %}
                  {% if categ == book.category.all.last %}
                    {{ categ }}
                  {% else %}
                    {{categ}}-
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </p>
              <h2 class="price">{{ book.price }} EGP.</h2>
              <h3 class="rate">{{ book.rate }}</h3>
              <a href="{% url 'buy' %}" target="_blank"
                ><button class="buy_now nav buy_now_position">Buy Now</button></a
              >
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <header class="nav">
          <a class="nav logo">
            <img
              src="{% static 'images/Main Logo.png' %}"
              class="logo"
              alt="logo"
            />
          </a>
          <a class="nav">All</a>
          <a class="nav">Horror</a>
          <a class="nav">Classics</a>
          <a class="nav">Graphic Novel</a>
          <a class="nav">Fantasy</a>
          <div class="drop_down nav">
            <a
              class="drop_down_btn nav"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup
            >
              more
          </a>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down menu"></i>
            <div class="drop_down-content nav">
              <a class="nav">Action and Adventure</a>
              <a class="nav">Detective and Mystery</a>
              <a class="nav">Fiction</a>
              <a class="nav">Romance</a>
              <a class="nav">Short Stories</a>
              <a class="nav">Educational</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control">
            <button class="filter nav" type="button">
              <i
                class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down-wide-short"
                id="toggle-filter"
              ></i>
            </button>
            <label>
              <input type="search" placeholder="search..." class="search" />
            </label>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="panel nav">
        <h2>Filter:</h2>
        <p>Enter the range of the prices you want</p>
        <br />
        <label>
          From:
          <input type="number" min="0" />
        </label>
        <br /><br />
        <label>
          To:
          <input type="number" min="0" />
        </label>
        <br /><br />
        <button type="button">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% if is_paginated %}
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
          {% endif %}
          {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
              <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

The error is raised at the line

```
src="{% static 'images/Main Logo.png' %}"
```

Edit: My Base file is as follows I Forgot to Include it in the question

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="author" content="Mohammad Ayman" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/style.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/details_style.css' %}" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/Title Bar Logo.png' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'js-files/jquery-3.6.0.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js-files/home.js' %}"></script>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2a5c8c2bca.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/buy_style.css' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'js-files/buy.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %} {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I've search for an answer but didn't find any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% extends "Books/base.html" %}
{% load static %}   <!--You need to load static here -->
{% block content %}
  
    <div class="page" id="page">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="main-content">
          {% for book in books %}
            <div class="container">
              <div class="img">
                <img
                  src="{{ book.image.url }}"
                  width="250px"
                  height="300px"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                <a href="{% url 'details' book.id %}" target="_blank"> {{ book.title }} </a>
              </div>
              <p class="description">{{ book.mini_description }}</p>
              <p class="category">
                {% for categ in book.category.all %}
                  {% if categ == book.category.all.last %}
                    {{ categ }}
                  {% else %}
                    {{categ}}-
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </p>
              <h2 class="price">{{ book.price }} EGP.</h2>
              <h3 class="rate">{{ book.rate }}</h3>
              <a href="{% url 'buy' %}" target="_blank"
                ><button class="buy_now nav buy_now_position">Buy Now</button></a
              >
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <header class="nav">
          <a class="nav logo">
            <img
              src="{% static 'images/Main Logo.png' %}"
              class="logo"
              alt="logo"
            />
          </a>
          <a class="nav">All</a>
          <a class="nav">Horror</a>
          <a class="nav">Classics</a>
          <a class="nav">Graphic Novel</a>
          <a class="nav">Fantasy</a>
          <div class="drop_down nav">
            <a
              class="drop_down_btn nav"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup
            >
              more
          </a>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down menu"></i>
            <div class="drop_down-content nav">
              <a class="nav">Action and Adventure</a>
              <a class="nav">Detective and Mystery</a>
              <a class="nav">Fiction</a>
              <a class="nav">Romance</a>
              <a class="nav">Short Stories</a>
              <a class="nav">Educational</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control">
            <button class="filter nav" type="button">
              <i
                class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down-wide-short"
                id="toggle-filter"
              ></i>
            </button>
            <label>
              <input type="search" placeholder="search..." class="search" />
            </label>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div class="panel nav">
        <h2>Filter:</h2>
        <p>Enter the range of the prices you want</p>
        <br />
        <label>
          From:
          <input type="number" min="0" />
        </label>
        <br /><br />
        <label>
          To:
          <input type="number" min="0" />
        </label>
        <br /><br />
        <button type="button">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% if is_paginated %}
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
          {% endif %}
          {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
              <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I 've added the load static tag in the base.html file I add the base content in the question

Comment: @MahammadAyman, Please add: `{% load static %}`  after `{% extends "Books/base.html" %}`

Comment: I did and it worked thanks but why didn't the tag that is in the base.html work?